# Cakephp Avoid wrong condition betweeen models

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.5, and need to join `Vehicle` table with `Address` table where `vei_id` is the foreign key

I have one find operation that is generating a wrong condition for the two models: `Vehicle` and `Address`.

`Address` has the `vei_id` column wich is the foreign key to join the vehicle table.

The query is generating `vehicle_id` as the column to join the two tables, the probem is that this column does not even exists.

I have mapped the two models using the `vei_id` column.

How can i avoid this situation ?  seems cakephp try to guess the join column even if i have already write the condition using the column i want.

```
//Vehicle Model
public $hasOne = array(
            'Address' => array(
                'className'  => 'Address',
                'conditions' => array('Vehicle.vei_id = Address.vei_id'),
                'foreignkey' => false
            )

//Address Model
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Vehicle' => array(
        'className' => 'Vehicle',
        'conditions'=> array('Vehicle.vei_id=Address.vei_id'),
        'foreignKey' => 'vei_id'
    ),
);

//At vehiclecontroller
$data = $this->Vehicle->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Vehicle.vei_id' => $vehicleId),
    'contain' => array(
        'Address' => array('conditions'=>  array('Address.vei_id'=>'Vehicle.vei_id',
                                                          'Vehicle.vei_id' => $vehicleId
                                            ),
                            )),
));
```

it generates this line :

```
LEFT JOIN Address ON (
    Address.vehicle_id = Vehicle.vei_id
    AND Address.vei_id = 'Vehicle.vei_id'
    AND Vehicle.vei_id = 123
)
```

Where this column does not exists :

```
Address.vehicle_id = Vehicle.vei_id
```

Comment: why you using Vehicle.vei_id ? Do you have vei_id column in vehicles table ? Looks like it should be Vehicle.id .

Comment: there is a internal convention to name the primary keys in this way, the vei_id column exists, the vehicle_id does not exists . So my only choice is try to adapt cakephp to the previous existing relational model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks little bit confusing:

*Just look at following conditions within contain:*

```
'contain' => array(
    'Address' => array('conditions'=>  
         array(
            'Address.vei_id'=>'Vehicle.vei_id', // why is this ?
            'Vehicle.vei_id' => $vehicleId
           ),
));
```

Why are you using following conditions within contain ?

```
 Address.vei_id'=>'Vehicle.vei_id
```

*Did you do that to join two tables ?*

When you use contain these things are done by cakephp's convention.
Address table is already joined with vehicle table.

See here:[Cakephp contain](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

*Also why not to follow cakephp convention?*

```
 If you have vehicles table,
 the foreign key would be vehicle_id according to cakephp convention. 
 And if you have users table foreign key would be user_id.
```

These things also reduces your work and make things easier.

See Here: ([cakephp model and database conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)).